# Trying to HideAllOtherApplications in AppDelegate

Tags: macos, swift, osx-yosemite, appdelegate

I have been trying to find a way to hide other applications programmaticly in my AppDelegate. I tried:

```
func hide() {
NSLog("hide")
NSApplication.hideOtherApplications(self)
}
```

> The error seems to be in the "self". I am pretty sure it is a really simple error but I keep on having issues trying to work it out.

But this does not seem to work. I am new to OS X programming. Although I already worked a bit (just a little bit) with swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().hideOtherApplications()

NSApplication.sharedApplication().hideOtherApplications(self)

NSApplication.sharedApplication().unhideAllApplications(self)
```

There is no `unhideAllApplications` for `NSWorkspace`. Please check the reference from Apple website.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I would still have a question. How am I able to unhide it. this did not work:     `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().unhideAllApplications()`

Comment: Try this: NSApplication.sharedApplication().unhideAllApplications(self)